# Manage a long-running operation node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am creating a telegram bot, which allows you to get some information about the destiny 2 game world, using the Bungie API. The bot is based on the Bot Framework and uses Telegram as a channel (as a language I am using JavaScript).

now I find myself in the situation where when I send a request to the bot it sends uses series of HTTP calls to the EndPoints of the API to collect information, format it and resubmit it via Adaptive cards, this process however in many cases takes more than 15 seconds showing in chat the message "POST to DestinyVendorBot timed out after 15s" (even if this message is shown the bot works perfectly).

Searching online I noticed that there doesn't seem to be a way to hide this message or increase the time before it shows up. So the only thing left for me to do is to make sure it doesn't show up. To do this I tried to refer to this documentation [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-long-operations-guidance?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). But the code shown is in C #, could someone give me an idea on how to solve this problem of mine or maybe some sample code?

I leave here an example of a call that takes too long and generates the message:

```
 //Mostra l'invetraio dell'armaiolo
    if (LuisRecognizer.topIntent(luisResult) === 'GetGunsmith') {
        //Take more 15 seconds
        const mod = await this.br.getGunsmith(accessdata, process.env.MemberShipType, process.env.Character);

        if (mod.error == 0) {

            var card = {
            }

            await step.context.sendActivity({
                text: 'Ecco le mod vendute oggi da Banshee-44:',
                attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)]
            });
        } else {
            await step.context.sendActivity("Codice di accesso scaduto.");
            await this.loginStep(step);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar where you call another function and send the message once the function is complete via proactive message. In my case, I set up the function directly inside the bot instead of as a separate Azure Function. First, you need to save the conversation reference somewhere. I store this in conversation state, and resave it every turn (you could probably do this in `onMembersAdded` but I chose `onMessage` when I did it so it resaves the conversation reference every turn). You'll need to import `const { TurnContext } = require('botbuilder')` for this.

```js
// In your onMessage handler
const conversationData = await this.dialogState.get(context, {});
conversationData.conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);
await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);
```

You'll need this for the proactive message. When it's time to send the API, you'll need to send a message (well technically that's optional but recommended), get the conversation data if you haven't gotten it already, and call the API function **without awaiting it**. If your API is always coming back around 15 seconds, you may just want a standard message (e.g. "One moment while I look that up for you"), but if it's going to be longer I would recommend setting the expectation with the user (e.g. "I will look that up for you. It may take up to a minute to get an answer. In the meantime you can continue to ask me questions."). **You should be saving user/conversation state further down in your turn handler.** Since you are not awaiting the call, the turn will end and the bot will not hang up or send the timeout message. Here is what I did with a simulation I created.

```js
await dc.context.sendActivity(`OK, I'll simulate a long-running API call and send a proactive message when it's done.`);
const conversationData = await this.dialogState.get(context, {});
apiSimulation.longRunningRequest(conversationData.conversationReference);

// That is in a switch statement. At the end of my turn handler I save state
await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);
await this.userState.saveChanges(context);
```

And then the function that I called. As this was just a simulation, I have just awaited a promise, but obviously you would call and `await` your API(s). Once that comes back you will create a new BotFrameworkAdapter to send the proactive message back to the user.

```js
const request = require('request-promise-native');
const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');

class apiSimulation {
    static async longRunningRequest(conversationReference) {
        console.log('Starting simulated API');
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 30000));
        console.log('Simulated API complete');
        
        // Set up the adapter and send the message
        try {
            const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
                appId: process.env.microsoftAppID,
                appPassword: process.env.microsoftAppPassword,
                channelService: process.env.ChannelService,
                openIdMetadata: process.env.BotOpenIdMetadata
            });
            await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
                await turnContext.sendActivity('This message was sent after a simulated long-running API');
            });
        } catch (error) {
            //console.log('Bad Request. Please ensure your message contains the conversation reference and message text.');
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}

module.exports.apiSimulation = apiSimulation;
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your response. i did a little test with your code and it seems to work, now i will proceed implementing it in all calls. only one thing is not clear to me: only one thing is not clear to me: what is `await this.conversationState.saveChanges (context) for;
await this.userState.saveChanges (context); ` ? anyway this was only half the problem, I have to manage a login process as well, but I guess now that I understand how it works it shouldn't be a problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: At the end of your main turn handler, I think you need those statements to save state so that dialogs can proceed as expected. I'm not an expert at how bot state works, but I know if you start a dialog and don't save state at the end of the turn, the bot stops responding correctly.